# PyQt4 installed but "ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4"' in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed PyQt4 using apt as follows:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt4
```

But I still get an error as:

```
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

when I do

```
import PyQt4
```

System specs:

```
Python 3.5.2
ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

Checked other threads of https://stackoverflow.com/ where people have faced similar problems but solutions provided seem specific to Mac and Win installations. If somebody can kindly help.

Comment: You probably have more than one python installed and you're using the wrong one.

Comment: @ekhumoro  I installed PyQt4 in my Python 3.5.2 virtualenv. Correct me if I am wrong -  installations using apt in virtualenvs are available systemwide. Interestingly "import PyQt4" works in Python3 outside my virtualenv , but not in my Python3 virtualenvironment.

Comment: But according to your question, you *didn't* install pyqt4 in the virtualenv - which explains why you can't import it there.

Comment: I assumed that "sudo apt install"  makes packages available system wide even if installed from virtualenvironment (Reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install). I also tried "pip install PyQt4" in my venv which doesn't install and gives a message "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for PyQt4".  Moreover I have also tried  "pyvenv-3.5 env1 --system-site-packages" to get access to global site-package modules in my virtual environment. But still no success.

Comment: I created a new VE with both `pyvenv --system-site-packages dir` and `virtualenv --system-site-packages dir`, and had no problem importing modules from the system installation.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your command with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```